# How do I make two bootstrap buttons side by side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set buttons on a modal side by side. One is a download link and the other is a mirror. I tried creating my own class with the css of display: inline-block; but that didnt work. How do I make them side by side?

Heres my code for my modal:

```
<!-- Texturepack Popup Start -->

    <div class = "modal fade" id = "texturepack" role = "dialog">
        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <h4>Texture Pack Download</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                    <center><h3>Download our Custom Texture Pack!</h3></center>
                    <p class = "tpbutton btn-toolbar">
                    <a style = "margin: 0 200px; display: inline-block" class = "btn navbar-btn btn-primary pull-center" href = "#" target = "_texturepack">Download</a>
                    <a style = "margin: 0 300px; display: inline-block" class = "btn navbar-btn btn-default pull-center" href = "#" target = "_texturepack">Mirror</a>
                    </p>
<!-- Carousel Text Start -->
    <div style = "height:15px"></div>
    <div style = "border: 2px solid black; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto" id = "textureCarousel" class = "carousel slide">
    
        <ol class = "carousel-indicators" data-ride = "carousel">
            <li data-target = "#textureCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active"></li>
            <li data-target = "#textureCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
            <li data-target = "#textureCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
        </ol>
    
        <div class = "carousel-inner">
    
            <div class = "item active">
                <img src = "img/a.png" alt = "Beach" class = "img-responsive">
            </div>

            <div class = "item">
                <img src = "img/b.png" alt = "Beach" class = "img-responsive">
            </div>

            <div class = "item">
                <img src = "img/c.png" alt = "Beach" class = "img-responsive">
            </div>
    
        </div>
        
    </div>      
    
<!-- Carousel End -->
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-footer">
                    <a class = "btn btn-danger" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Texturepack Popup End -->
```

Comment: how are they displayed in this version? The second one below the first one?

Answer (score 92):

Use a button group.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Mirror</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks i was looking for something like this yesterday

Comment: This will change the borders on the buttons fyi

Answer (score 10):

Try this putting `text-align:center` on the outer element:

```
<p class = "tpbutton btn-toolbar" style="text-align:center">
     <a class = "btn navbar-btn btn-primary" href = "#" target = "_texturepack">Download</a>
     <a class = "btn navbar-btn btn-default" href = "#" target = "_texturepack">Mirror</a>
</p>
```

[**Demonstration**](http://bootply.com/104143)

**EDIT:** Or by using the [`text-center`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) class:

```
<p class = "tpbutton btn-toolbar text-center">
     <a class = "btn navbar-btn btn-primary" href = "#" target = "_texturepack">Download</a>
     <a class = "btn navbar-btn btn-default" href = "#" target = "_texturepack">Mirror</a>
</p>
```

[**Demonstration**](http://www.bootply.com/6xwwKEseYn)

Comment: It perfectly works. Also since it uses a ```<p>``` container you can use ```pull-left``` and ```pull-right``` if you want to align to the very left and the very right.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was hanging for 20 minutes.
Finally

```
<td class="text-nowrap">
```

worked.

Answer (score 5):

While `btn-group` works, it removes the space between the two buttons:

For instance, this code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Transaction History</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Make New Payment
        </button>
      </div>
```

will give you this:

[image]

If you want space between the buttons, use `btn-toolbar` instead:

```
 <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-left: 15px">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Transaction History</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Make New Payment
        </button>
      </div>
```

[image]

I added styling because without it, the buttons are aligned to the left. Change the padding value to your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the `pull-left` `pull-right` in bootstrap3 like

```
<button class = "btn-primary pull-left">Download</button>
<button class = "btn-danger pull-right">Mirror</button>
```

Comment: it wont align elements side by side.

Comment: Yeah, I found that out too. The pull-right throws the button way over to the right side of the screen. It does what it says it should do. silly me

Answer (score 4):

For people looking two create two buttons side by side, full width, just with Bootstrap (4) classes, you could use the following:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-block">
    <button class="btn btn-danger mr-2 rounded">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success ml-2 rounded">Save</button>
</div>
```

Explanation: the btn-group class connects the buttons and the btn-block makes them full width. The individual buttons have a margin (mr-2 and ml-2) to disconnect them (but keep them side by side) and the rounded class makes the corners of the disconnected buttons rounded again.

Answer (score 3):

**With bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="float-right">
   <button>Cancel</button>
   </button>Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Neither the text-center or btn-group solution worked for me.  I ended up putting the two buttons in a row together and that worked.

```
<div class="row">
  <%= button_to "Delete", "#", :class=>"btn" %>  
  <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
```